# Javascript .innerHTML; Issue

Tags: javascript, html

Okay for a little background I am creating an HTML email signature generator for a client and have run into an issue multiple times. I created a function that allows the user to download the file as a.html so they may install it into their email platform of choice. The problem I am running into a lot is for some reason when using # anywhere in the index.html file it seems like the code stops there when downloading. I assume the # is somehow interfering with the.innerHTML; making it stop for some reason.

I will attach my codepen.io bare in mind there isn't much CSS as I have just started on this and wanted to get the functionality working before making the signature look nice.

link: https://codepen.io/andrewnyrivera/pen/XWaELwL

```
/* DOWNLOAD! */
    function download() {
      var filename = document.getElementById("filename").value;
      var a = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
      a.download = filename + ".html";
      a.href =
        "data:text/html," + document.getElementById("content").innerHTML; // Grab the HTML
      a.click(); // Trigger a click on the element
    }
```

Also here is an image of how the code is cut off, you can see this in inspect element after you download the file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bo44W.png)

Comment: Use the [Blob API](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/API/Blob) instead of manually constructing `data:` URLs.

Comment: Ty will try it out! Do you know why it doesn't work when using data: or why I should use data: in the first place?

Comment: `data:text/html,something something something#fragment` -- I wonder what could be causing the URL to be cut off?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm pretty noob could you elaborate more ty.

Comment: @AndrewRivera [Wikipedia](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Syntax).

Comment: @SebastianSimon Thank you very much for the resource!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out!!!! Thank you to those who have helped guide me! I did some research based on what I was told about the UTF-8 not allowing # symbols and that the # symbol fragments the URL. I ended up putting the "document.getElementById("content")" as a variable and then did "encodeURIComponent(content)". I am not 100% sure why it works but will find out. I assume it encodes it to where the # is no longer there until decoded back to # there for not fragmenting the URL.

```
function download() { 
  var filename = document.getElementById("filename").value; 
  var content = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML; 
  var a = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("a")); 
  a.download = filename + ".html"; 
  a.href = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(content); 
  a.click(); // Trigger a click on the element
}
```

Thank you to those who help!

Best,

Andrew

Comment: function download() {
  var filename = document.getElementById("filename").value;
  var content = document.getElementById("content").innerHTML;
  var a = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement("a"));
  a.download = filename + ".html";
  a.href = "data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(content);
  a.click(); // Trigger a click on the element
}

Comment: Ty very much @GolezTrol